# How can I get successful and not successful controls with jQuery .serialize() for a GET Parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I totally screwd my code and application logic by forgetting that .serialize() only gives me checked elements (checkboxes) of my form. I really need ALL elements because i have to recreate small arrays with the elements in the right order.

Let's say i have 10 checkboxes with the id/names box1 to box10 - now only checkbox 4 and 6 are checked therefore the output is:

...&box4=on&box6=on... but I also need &box1=(whatever just unlike "on" so i can differ) and the other 8 boxes :/.

I shoudld also mention that i have input type textfields and textareas - so it's a mixed thingy. I don't have only checkboxes.

Any ideas?

regards

Comment: One (kludgy) idea that comes to mind is to turn all checkboxes into selects on the fly before serializing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use .serialize(). iterate over all the checks and create the query string yourself.

mixed solution:

```
var query1='', query2=[];
query1=$('#myForm').serialize();
$('#myform :checkbox').not(':checked').each(function(){
    query2.push($(this).attr('name')+'=off');
});
query1+='&'+query2.join('&');
```

or something like that

Comment: Sry i just updated my question. I can't iterate with the same algorythm because i have also textfields and textareas which cannot be checked :/

Comment: so? serialize manually the textboxes, use .serialize() on the textboxes and concatenate both strings, use .serialize() and concatenate a manual string for the unchecked chekboxes. any of your choice

Comment: I know you've chosen an answer, but have a look at my solution aswell. It looked less complicated.

Comment: @Robin_Castlin: it is a javascript-jquery question, so i gave a javascript-jquery answer. i don't see it too complicated in any case, and avoids creating innecesary elements

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to do like this:

```
<?php

foreach(range(1, 10) as $h)
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="box'.$h.'" value="false" />';

?>
```

Inserted before your checkboxes. Replace "false".

And if the checkbox is checked, it's value will overwrite the hidden element.